# После того, как поменял hibernate.cfg.xml на реализацию в java-классе возникла ошибка. В чем причина?

Tags: hibernate, java-ee, spring-mvc, spring-boot

В чем может быть причина, указанных ниже ошибок?

Exceptions:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userServiceHib'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOReal' defined in file [C:\JProjects\SpringQuiz\out\artifacts\Servlet1_war_exploded\WEB-INF\classes\dao\UserDAOReal.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in config.AppConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userServiceHib'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOReal' defined in file [C:\JProjects\SpringQuiz\out\artifacts\Servlet1_war_exploded\WEB-INF\classes\dao\UserDAOReal.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in config.AppConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOReal' defined in file [C:\JProjects\SpringQuiz\out\artifacts\Servlet1_war_exploded\WEB-INF\classes\dao\UserDAOReal.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in config.AppConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in config.AppConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

class HibernateConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"controllers","model","dao","service"})
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"model"});
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(datasource());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource datasource(){
        BasicDataSource dataSource=new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/quizzes");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("dbpass");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(@Autowired SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        HibernateTransactionManager manager= new HibernateTransactionManager();
        manager.setDataSource(datasource());
        manager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return manager;
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

      <context:component-scan base-package="config"/>


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
 <!-- Hibernate-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Spring Boot and MVC-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

По ошибкам видно, что не создается бин `sessionFactory`. Вот примерно код, который должен его создавать

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
  LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
  sessionFactory.setDataSource(datasource());
  sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
    new String[] { "model" });
  sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

  return sessionFactory;
}

Properties hibernateProperties() {
  return new Properties() {
     {            
        setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "MySQL");
        setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers",
         "true");
     }
  };
}
```